# Hadoop data nodes stops reporting

Tags: hadoop

I have a 4 node (master + 3 slave) cluster running hadoop 0.20.203.0. Every few days, datanodes will become reported as dead on the master. On the slave, everything appears fine and the datanode process is still running, with nothing suspicious in the logs, although it is no longer receiving any requests. On the master, the logs show that the datanode heartbeat has been lost.

The only solution is to manually stop the datanode and then start it again. After several minutes the datanode becomes reported as live again.

Has anyone else experienced this? If so what was the cause, and the solution?

Comment: Sounds like you might be having trouble with network hardware.  Do you lose only one slave at a time or several?  Also, are you on EC2 or some other virtualized environment?

Comment: Running on direct hardware on our own servers. What gives you the clue that it may be network hardware related? Can I turn on some kind of logging to be able to tell whether the datanode thinks that it is sending heartbeats? Can a datanode get in a bad state in which it gives up on trying to send a heartbeat?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, we lose one at a time. Hopefully our monitoring notices it and we restart it before the next one does the same thing.

Comment: I think network hardware when I hear that someone is experiencing a connectivity loss issue that isn't widely reported (especially on their own hardware), because that suggests something environmental.  Are you deleting large directories?  If so, you might be experiencing https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-611. You can turn DataNode logging up to Info level, but that will be extremely verbose.  When a datanode is marked dead by the NN, all data is considered lost, and needs to be re-replicated when the node is brought back online.

Comment: To change datanode log level, see http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hadoop.hbase.user/10284.  Looks like 
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSNamesystem.audit=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace=INFO

Comment: In another way, how can we start the dead node servers without using start-all.sh script. thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

We had similar problem,  for us solusion was to increase open file limit.

Try add line like `ulimit -n 4096` to file `hadoop-env.sh`

Comment: Thanks, but our ulimit is already set very high: `ulimit -n 1048576`

Comment: In fact it looks like this, combined with another bug was the cause of our problem. Our configuration was messed up and some nodes had a lower ulimit (0124)

Answer (score 3):

There were two issues.

1) The underlying issue, as suggested by Tomas above was that the open file limit was set incorrectly.

2) The secondary issue was in error handling and reporting. This is described in the hadoop bug database [Datanode is marked dead, but datanode process is alive and verifying blocks](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-1766).

When the thread that sends heartbeats to the namenode failed, it did not recover well.

a) No more heartbeat attempts were ever made, and it did not cause the entire datanode to shut down.
b) It reported the error to stderr or stdout, which usually goes into a .out file instead of through log4j, which does to the usual .log file (and I forgot that the .out file even existed, so I didn't check there.)

Answer (score 0):

In our case, It happened due to OutOfMemoryError. We found the error in data node .out file.